# Can I add a new source code class to an existing package in Android?

Tags: android, apk

I want to extend a class that exists in the android.support.v7.widget package. The class contains several members that have package scope that I want to use, so I want the class to be a part of that

To do that I created the package `android.support.v7.widget` in my Android app. The class works fine in debug builds but not in release builds. When I use the analyze APK functionality in Android Studio I can see that the class is included in the release APK, but I keep getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget...` errors when using the release APK.

Note that `android.support.v7.widget` is a package that exists in Android namespace. Could that be the cause of the failure?

Comment: Are you using ProGuard in your `release` builds? Is there anything referring to your added class that would trigger ProGuard to keep it?

Comment: I turned off ProGuard to see if it is the cause. It is imported and seems to exist in the final APK, but it's still not found when I run the APK.

Comment: So it works in a `debug`, but does not work in a ProGuard-less `release` build? If so, I have no explanation for that.

Comment: Oh boy, I'm an idiot, I used a stale build of the APK. It works when I turn ProGuard off.

Comment: In fact, it even works when ProGuard is on but without specifying ``minifyEnabled true``

Comment: @CommonsWare It turned out that adding a -keep directive to the proguard file was all that was necessary - if you want to add an answer to that effect I'll accept it 'cause you were the one who pointed me in the right direction. :)

Comment: Actually, I recommend that you answer your own question. Show where you were using this class (so we can see why ProGuard wasn't detecting its usage), and then explain your fix. All I can do is echo your comment -- you're in position to provide a lot more clarity of how you got into this situation in the first place. Regardless, I'm glad to hear that it is working!

Comment: Hmm, do you have any pointers as to how I should trace ProGuard's steps? I did reference the class in an Activity, so it doesn't fit any of the cases listed in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-code

Comment: That might be worthy of a separate Stack Overflow question, showing how you are using the class and inquiring why you needed a `-keep` rule.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that ProGuard failed to realize that the class must be kept.

Adding a `-keep public class ClassName { *; }` statement to the ProGuard file fixed this.